# Filter date to be greater than 24 months rather than 2 years?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ListKey
FROM Closing_List
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,closedate) > DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())-2)
```

But I want 24 Months back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ListKey
FROM Closing_List
WHERE closedate > DATEADD(MONTH, -24, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: @Sewder Sorry, I mixed the order of the arguments. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ListKey
FROM Closing_List
WHERE closedate > DATEADD(MONTH,-24,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DATEADD` is fine as long as you know what it's doing with the dates.

`GetDate()` returns the current date and time. Right now for me that's `08/30/2013 02:18:14pm`

Passing that through `DATEADD(MONTH,-24,GETDATE())` yields `08/30/2011 02:18:14pm'`

So if I were running your query with that information it would be giving me all results with a closedate greater than (not equal to) `08/30/2011 02:18:14pm`. There are a couple of things to consider about that.

For one, if you have records that closed on 08/30/2011 at 1:00pm then they won't be included in your results. Moreover if your close dates don't have times at all then you won't get *any* records from 08/30/2011.

Also note that if you run that query on 9/2/2013 then it won't include records from 9/1/2011. That may or may not be a problem, depending on your needs.

Another solution might be:

```
SELECT ListKey
FROM Closing_List
WHERE closedate >= dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-24,0)
```

If you run the above anytime in September of 2013 it will include all records with a close date from September 2011 to September 2013. It doesn't care about what day of the month it currently is or if the close date includes time data.